# Working twitter login turns into 401

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I've had twitter login working on my site for years. I randomly decided to test it today and found out it was not working.

I am using dotnetopenauth 3.4.7.11121 . I have twitterConsumerKey and twitterConsumerSecret in my web config. Thoughts on where to troubleshoot first?

The error is "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

My code of note:

```
public static OutgoingWebResponse StartSignInWithTwitter(bool forceNewLogin)
    {
        var redirectParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (forceNewLogin)
        {
            redirectParameters["force_login"] = "true";
        }
        Uri callback = MessagingUtilities.GetRequestUrlFromContext().StripQueryArgumentsWithPrefix("oauth_");
        var request = TwitterSignIn.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, null, redirectParameters);
        return TwitterSignIn.Channel.PrepareResponse(request);
    }
```

The exception:

```
    [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6442312
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\StandardWebRequestHandler.cs:126

[ProtocolException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.]
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\StandardWebRequestHandler.cs:169
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\StandardWebRequestHandler.cs:100
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.GetDirectResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:622
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:644
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:467
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\Messaging\Channel.cs:447
   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ConsumerBase.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(Uri callback, IDictionary`2 requestParameters, IDictionary`2 redirectParameters, String& requestToken) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a02b428f36957bca\src\DotNetOpenAuth\OAuth\ConsumerBase.cs:221
   TwitterConsumer.StartSignInWithTwitter(Boolean forceNewLogin) in c:\TFSWebForms\www.nanaimo.ca\Nanaimo.Ca\openID\TwitterConsumer.cs:207
   openID_login.ibTwitter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\TFSWebForms\www.nanaimo.ca\Nanaimo.Ca\openID\login.aspx.cs:717
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +116
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9643314
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

**UPDATE**
I used fiddler and found that that dotnetopenauth is not forwarding the authentication when it gets redirected from http to https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my issue. Twitter seems to have started forcing https and the redirect stopped working. I updated my twitter consumer to change it to https from http. My consumer was taken from the samples.

```
/// <summary>
        /// The description of Twitter's OAuth protocol URIs for use with actually reading/writing
        /// a user's private Twitter data.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription ServiceDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription
        {
            RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// The description of Twitter's OAuth protocol URIs for use with their "Sign in with Twitter" feature.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription SignInWithTwitterServiceDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription
        {
            RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
        };
```

Semi related: my old timeline URL "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/14529984.xml" changed to https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/14529984.xml at some point breaking another feature of my app.

Comment: I know this is old, but THANK YOU for submitting this solution!

Comment: No , problem. I should also not that the timelines are no longer available at either link because of the API change.